# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync при авторизации через Facebook возвращает null

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, .net-core, аутентификация

Я добавил авторизацию через facebook в Startup, решил уже туда все что можно запихать в попытках решить проблему:

```
 .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                    facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
                    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");
                    facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
                    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("name");
                    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("email");
                    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("first_name");
                    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("last_name");

                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey("urn:facebook:age_range_min", "age_range", "min");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey("urn:facebook:age_range_max", "age_range", "max");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "birthday");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "first_name");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:facebook:middle_name", "middle_name");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "last_name");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Gender, "gender");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:facebook:link", "link");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonSubKey("urn:facebook:location", "location", "name");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Locality, "locale");
                    facebookOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:facebook:timezone", "timezone");



                })
```

В контролере добавил такой метод:

```
 public IActionResult SignIn(String provider)
        {
            var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("FacebookLoginCallback",
                    new { returnUrl = "QQQQQQQQQQQ" })
            };
            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }
```

При переходе по https://localhost:5002/api/Authentication?provider=Facebook происходит редирект на авторизацию в Facebook. И после ввода пароля попадает в метод FacebookLoginCallback:

```
public async Task<string> GoogleLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
           var info = await AuthManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
           ...
```

Где info чтобы я не делал остается null.
Я попробовал переписать метод GetExternalLoginInfoAsync таким образом:

```
 public virtual async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(
            string expectedXsrf = null)
        {
            AuthenticateResult auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            IDictionary<string, string> items = auth?.Properties?.Items;
            string providerKey = auth.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
            string provider = "Facebook";
            if (providerKey == null || provider == null)
                return (ExternalLoginInfo) null;
            return new ExternalLoginInfo(auth.Principal, provider, providerKey, (await AuthManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).FirstOrDefault<AuthenticationScheme>((Func<AuthenticationScheme, bool>) (p => p.Name == provider))?.DisplayName ?? provider)
            {
                AuthenticationTokens = auth.Properties.GetTokens()
            };
        }
```

Т. е. заменил this.Context.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);`на HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
И напрямую написал provider. И о чудо мне стало хоть что-то возвращать. Но к сожалению не все. 
[image: Пример того что есть в info._identity]
Никакой информации хотя бы о email или всего того что я описал в стартапе не вижу и не пойму как получить. Ясно что я чего-то не понимаю и делаю не так, но к сожалению информации в интернете подходящей так и не нашел, хотя и вопросов с подобным заголовками достаточно. Может кто сталкивался и сможет подсказать?

Comment: В хроме, если нажать F12, есть консоль для отладки, там можно смотреть все запросы и ответы к серверу. Какой запрос вам фейсбук отправляет? Даже на msdn есть пример причем именно с аутентификацией через фейсбук, смотрели его?

Comment: В данном случае ответ не посмотреть так как происходят редиректы. Но на сколько я понимаю, конкретно, к фейсбуку претензий нет, он и на запрос количества лайков отреагировал предупреждением. Скорее всего я именно как-то неправильно обрабатываю этот ответ. На msdn написанно что "создайте MVS проект, напишите AddFacebook и у вас все само подключится". И ни примера контролера, ничего. У меня api проект и я хочу все на стороне бэка сделать, Но пока не могу эту проблему решить. Попробую гугл настроить, с ним вроде проблем меньше насколько я читал.

Comment: Ставите галочку [вот тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aPMY.png) и консоль не будет очищаться на редиректах. На msdn целый [раздел о фeйсбуке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2) и там где то есть даже тестовое приложение - это то,что вам нужно?

Comment: Да я читал эту статью и собственно ничего полезного там нет. Создаешь такой проект. Там стартап и несколько вьюх, а весь процесс делается с помощью магии в какие-то закрытых методах. Ни контролеров, ни классов, ничего подобного. Что откуда не ясно?. Вот тут вроде что-то похожее.  [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2) . Но собственно ответ такой же null.  Консоль не очищается. Просто в запросе написано код 302 и раздел response пустой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разрешилось переустановкой net core